# How to get the DataGrid row data in Textboxs

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

How do I get the `DataGrid` row data while selecting a DataGrid. For example, while selecting a row in a DataGrid , I want to show that field data in concern TextBoxes. Please see the code snippet below

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbCode" runat="server" TabIndex="0"                        
                    style="width: 82px; position: absolute; top: 16px; left: 63px; width: 88px; height: 24px;" 
                    MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text="Code"                          
                    style="width: 45px; position: absolute; top: 18px; left: 18px; height: 22px;">
 </asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCode" runat="server" TabIndex="0"                        
                    style="width: 82px; position: absolute; top: 16px; left: 63px; width: 88px; height: 24px;" 
                    MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text="Code"                          
                    style="width: 45px; position: absolute; top: 18px; left: 18px; height: 22px;">
</asp:Label>

   <asp:DataGrid ID="Grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyField="Team_Id"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
        OnPageIndexChanged="Grid_PageIndexChanged" OnCancelCommand="Grid_CancelCommand"
        style="position:absolute; top: 122px; left: 13px; width: 545px; bottom: 238px;"
        OnDeleteCommand="Grid_DeleteCommand" OnEditCommand="Grid_EditCommand"             

        OnUpdateCommand="Grid_UpdateCommand" TabIndex="3" BorderStyle="Solid" 
        BorderWidth="1">

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Code" DataField="Team_Code" ReadOnly="true"> </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Team Name" DataField="Team_Name"> </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:EditCommandColumn  EditText="Edit" CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="Edit"> </asp:EditCommandColumn>
        <asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete"> </asp:ButtonColumn>            
    </Columns>          
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

updated code

```
    protected void GetSelectedData(Object src, EventArgs e)
{
    String TeamId = Grid.DataKeys[Grid.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    using (OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStr"]))
    {
        DbConnection.Close();
        string cmdText = "SELECT Team_Code,Team_Name FROM team_details WHERE Team_Id=?";
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, DbConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Id", OdbcType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TeamId);
        DbConnection.Open();
        OdbcDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (DR.Read())
        {
            tbCode.Text = DR.GetValue(0).ToString();
            tbName.Text = DR.GetValue(1).ToString();
        }

    }
}

  <asp:DataGrid ID="Grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyField="Team_Id"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
        OnSelectedChanged="GetSelectedData" OnCancelCommand="Grid_CancelCommand"
        style="position:absolute; top: 122px; left: 13px; width: 545px; bottom: 238px;"
        OnDeleteCommand="Grid_DeleteCommand" OnEditCommand="Grid_EditCommand"               
        OnUpdateCommand="Grid_UpdateCommand" TabIndex="3" BorderStyle="Solid" 
        BorderWidth="1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Code" DataField="Team_Code" ReadOnly="true"> </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Team Name" DataField="Team_Name"> </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:EditCommandColumn  EditText="Edit" CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="Edit"> </asp:EditCommandColumn>
        <asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete"> </asp:ButtonColumn>            
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="select" text="select team" />                    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn> 
    </Columns>
  </asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GridViewSelection Event for that

```
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="Grid_SelectedIndexChanged"


   void Grid_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

     // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
      GridViewRow row = Grid.SelectedRow;

     //Fill textboxes here
     Code.Text =  row.Cells[0].Text;

    }
```

Oh yeah this code is for grid.So if you are using datagrid You need to Set the Select CommandField in the Grid so that the SelectedIdexChanged event will fire up

[Here](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/shared/viewsrc.aspx?path=/aspxtreme/sys/web/ui/webcontrols/demos/datagridselectedindexchanged.aspx.src) is code sample that will definitely help you

Comment: showing an error message like `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRow' and no 
extension method 'SelectedRow' accepting a first argument 
of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: use protected void in this event definition and let me know please

Comment: I'm using protected void, see the code below, `protected void Grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
        GridViewRow row = Grid.SelectedRow;
        //Fill textboxes here
        tbCode.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
    }`

Comment: I'm using `DataGrid` not `GridView` component.

Comment: yeah right my mistake i aplogize. I have given you a link read this out i found it really helpful regarding datagrid.. In datagrid we have to apply CommandField to get row...Let me know if your problem get solved by this...

Comment: i will check and update to you, thanks a lot for your hearty help.

Comment: Syeda, I updated the code , but the while selecting the `linkButton` not firing the `OnSelectedChanged` event.Could you please give look on the code which is I'm updated in the original question.

Comment: OnSelectedChanged is not an event defined you are making a mistake here event is OnSelectedIndexChanged. change this and check...

Comment: yes, sorry it was a typo, apart from that I'm using some Required  Validation control also, so that validation blocking to trigger the event. finally i found out that the use of `ValidationGroup` property.Now its working fine. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

you can use java script for that..put check box in front of each row and then on the selected index changed of that check which row is selected and get the data and display it in the textbox you want..